# Overriden Standard Edit using NavigationMixin with overridden Cancel / Save URL

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I have encountered the same problem as the unanswered question found here: [backgroundContext not working for Edit NavigationMixin LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279122/backgroundcontext-not-working-for-edit-navigationmixin-lwc)

backgroundContext does not appear to work in this scenario - so I have tried many other parameters to no success:

- inContextOf - a base64 encoded string of a page reference. I have used this successfully in Aura components
- saveNewUrl - similar to backgroundContext, does not work. found from a record type selection screen url: [image] Some guessed urls based off what I've seen can be used in class:

  - cancelUrl - similar to backgroundContext, does not work
  - saveUrl- similar to backgroundContext, does not work

Is there any state variable that anyone can suggest? This state object is highly undocumented and has been a process of trial and error getting this to work in LWC.

```
    let pageReference = {
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: contactId,
            objectApiName: 'Contact',
            actionName: 'edit'
        },
        state: {
            nooverride: '1'
            //,backgroundContext: testUrl //works for view
            //,inContextOfRef: '1.' + window.btoa(JSON.stringify(inContextOf))
            //,saveNewUrl: testUrl
            //,saveUrl: testUrl
            //,cancelUrl: testUrl
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add in `state` the `navigationLocation` attribute. I have resolved the problem for the backgroundContext by adding it (see the linked question for the details and a full example).